# Issue on attaching csv & pdf file- Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uti

I'm working with PDF generation,it generated the PDF, viewed using `QLPreviewController`, all worked fine except mail forwarding, I have two attachments of type **.pdf** and **.csv**. I have the following issues while emailing.

- sometimes no attachments while emailing.
- pdf size will be very huge when pdf contains image(10 mb for one page
  pdf, if it contains image).

  Problem is when testing in device.., in simulator it all works fine..., I come to know some exporting or importing UTI associated issues here since I am a starter I feel difficult to understand it, I think some UTI's I have to add somewhere.. Can anyone please help me to identify the issue and solve, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't repeat your questions.

Comment: it is not answered!! since it is asked 2 days before, it is not getting noticed.. that is why i put it again.. i dont how it works! could you help me please!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: thanks.. then, how can i delete the duplicate question.